# EF Core 2.x: How can I compose and configure a same model class that is parent and child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I need a class to store data about `Department` where `Department` has many `Divisions`. The point is that both `Department` and `Division` has exactly the same properties. So I'd like to model only one class for that. Lets call it `Unit`. How can I achieve this? I tried with the model below. But is't not working.

```
    public class Unit
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public Unit Parent { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you say "its not working", could you give the specific error you are running into, simply saying "its not working" doesnt provide much of a starting place for trying to know the issue youre running into.

Comment: The error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Units_Units_ParentId' on table 'Units' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: Just like the error says, your databse provider doesn't support cascading deletes in this situation.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a bad idea because you can end up with the case that one `Division` has a list of `Divisions`. 
You should make a class `Unit` and then classes `Department` and `Division` which derive from `Unit` class.

```
 public class Unit
{
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Department : Unit 
{
    public IEnumerable<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
}

public class Division : Unit 
{
   public Department Department;
   public int DepartmentId;

}
```

Comment: Now you add more 2 classes. I don't want to have more then one class for this.